# Flipped / reversed fmap (<$>)?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pointfree

I found defining the following

```
(%)  = flip fmap
```

I can write code like this:

```
readFile "/etc/passwd" % lines % filter (not . null)
```

To me it makes more sense than the alternative:

```
filter (not . null) <$> lines <$> readFile "/etc/passwd"
```

Obviously, it's just a matter of order.

Does anyone else do this? Is there a valid reason not to write code like this?

Comment: The more common name for this is probably ```<&>``` following ```(&) = flip ($)``` by lens.

Answer (score 12):

```
(<&>) :: Functor f => f a -> (a -> b) -> f b
```

Now available from `Data.Functor` in  `base`.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--38--62-

Comment: Since `base` version 4.11.0.0

Answer (score 10):

Your operator `(%)` is exactly the operator [`(<&>)` from the lens package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Operators.html#v:-60--38--62-).

It can be imported with:

```
import Control.Lens.Operators ((<&>))
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a similar function for the `Applicative` type class called [`<**>`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.12.0.0/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--42--62-); it's a perfectly reasonable thing to want or use for Functor as well. Unfortunately, the semantics are a bit different for `<**>`, so it can't be directly widened to apply to `Functor` as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
-- (.) is to (<$>) as flip (.) is to your (%).
```

I usually define (&) = flip (.) and it's just like your example, you can apply function composition backwords.  Allows for easier to understand points-free code in my opinion.

Comment: There's also the Arrow combinator (>>>) which is the same as (flip (.)) for functions

Comment: Why thank you sir!  Other than the import boilerplate, this will be useful so I can keep standard code.

Comment: Note that lens defines ```(&) = flip ($)```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I wouldn't use such an operators because then I have to learn two orders in which to read programs.

Comment: Not sure I find this argument compelling enough, but it's an interesting point of view, so +1. Out of curiosity: do you prefer `=<<` over `>>=` for that same reason?

Comment: I never understood the previous statement.  It seems to make sense using standard notation because then it's like unix piping?

Comment: I prefer =<< to >>= because the form has a clear interpretation in terms of the Kleisli category of your monad which can be inverted to give an understandable definition for comonads.

Comment: Stephan: that said your argument seems I'll posed. Preferring >>= to =<< would be more appropriate as you are given the former and the other is derived. I realize you were after the argument order though.

Comment: I disagree. One *already* has to reverse the narration flow in deep function compositions (point-free style most notably), to be able to construe the data flow of the code. At the same time, `>>=` does lead to code flow which matches data flow. These together can easily lead to code lines like this: `action1 >>= action3 . action2 >>= action4`, where the reader has to *reverse his reading order multiple times in a line* to be able to understand the data flow pipeline. Flipped function composition will be helpful in this case.