# Mixing fmap and bind (>>=)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, coding-style

In Haskell, when I have to mix calls to `fmap`/`<$>` and `>>=`/`=<<`, I invariably end up with lots of parenthesis.

For example, here I'm calling `listDirectoryAbs dir :: IO [String]` and then chaining a series of `filter` and `filterM`, ending with a `fmap`.

```
findDlls :: String -> IO [String]
findDlls dir = f <$> (filterM predicate1 =<< (filter predicate2 <$> (filterM predicate3 =<< listDirectoryAbs dir)))
```

Because all these nested expressions look messy (at least to me), I end up rewriting `f <$> x` to `return . f =<< x`. If I then flip the binds, I get something more readable:

```
findDlls dir = listDirectoryAbs dir
 >>= filterM predicate3
 >>= return . filter predicate2
 >>= filterM predicate1
 >>= return . f
```

Is rewriting `f <$> x` -> `return . f =<< x` -> `x >>= return . f` "bad" in any way? Is there a preferable way of avoiding nested expressions in situations such as these?

I *could* use `do` notation instead, but I'd like to avoid having to be explicit about data flow and giving every return value a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's "bad" (unless it forfeits optimisations in `fmap` of that particular monad), however I don't like its verbosity.

I'd rather define my own operator for this, [`<$$>` has been suggested](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/Add-flipped-fmap-td3178048.html) or `<&>` would match the [`$`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-36-)/[`&`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-38-)-duality well (see also *[Anyone ever flip (<$>)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1678104/1048572)*):

```
infixl 1 <&>
(<&>) = flip (<$>)

findDlls dir = listDirectoryAbs dir
 >>= filterM predicate3
 <&> filter predicate2
 >>= filterM predicate1
 <&> f
```

Btw, if your monad is an [`Arrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:Arrow) (e.g. functions), then `<<<`/`>>>` combines nicely with `=<<`/`>>=`.